# Why am I getting verification errors with avrude?

Tags: avr, atmega, avrdude

I am constantly getting verification errors with avrdude and atmega168. I googled a lot, but everyone is getting them at first byte, whereas I am getting them at random bytes:

```
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0692
         0x91 != 0x8c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I noticed that if one hex file doesn't work once, it won't work at all, unless I will change something in code, thus changing the hex file. It happened with multiple processors and two programmers.

Comment: Lack of decoupling capacitors causing the chip to fwibble?

Comment: nope, they're there.

Comment: Have you been reprogramming it a lot? Are the power supply voltages in spec? What programmer are you using, which baudrate?

Comment: Did you tried with other uC?
@jippie the write/erase cycles are 10.000 for the flash memory according to the datasheet. Of-course this varies, and can be the case, but I think the changes are small.